# inter-region GKE Master Nodes Access

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-vpc

My co-workers are launching GKE clusters and managing them from a pair of centralized VMs.  The vms are in us-east4

When they launch GKE clusters in the same region (us-east4), all is well.  They can access both the worker nodes and also the GKE Master addresses via the peering connection.  However, they could not access the master nodes of a GKE cluster built in europe-west3.  I built a VM in that region, and was successfully able to connect to port 443 of the master node IPs.  Global routing is enabled for the VPC network and inter-region access of VMs and other services is no problem.

Seems very clear that GKE master nodes can only be accessed in the same region.  But is this documented somewhere?  I did open a support case on Monday, but having little luck getting any reasonable information back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this is an expected behavior. Since I have reviewed [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#endpoints), I understood the following information about it, but you are right, there is nothing like this on it:

The private IP address of the master in a regional cluster only could be reachable from the subnetworks that are in the same region, or from on-premises devices that are connected to the same region.

Now, based on [this](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/creating-kubernetes-engine-private-clusters-with-net-proxies), I would recommend you to set up a proxy on the same region where your GKE master is, in order to make all the requests coming from a different region, look like they come from the reachable region.

Please review [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59580847/access-private-gke-clusters-from-a-different-region), it is an example about how to reach your master from a cluster in another region.

Comment: Yes, another post here: https://www.reddit.com/r/googlecloud/comments/cohawr/how_to_route_traffic_to_gke_private_master_from/   Just seems very odd that all these documents list a solution without first stating the problem

Comment: I'm happy to know the answer was useful, in order to help the community in the future, could you please accept or upvote the answer? Thanks